# 2 dimensional char array creation/initialization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I've found my answer here multiple times both for programming problems, but thing is this time i can't, not in here, not in the web generally so here i am asking.

i'm getting this error
[image: Error msg: Syntax error on token ";",, expected.]

On the `public char pinakas[][]` - 4th line while i'm trying to create/initialize my 2 dimensional char array (it's going to store chars from A to Z)

```
public class Board {

    public char pinakas[][]; 
    pinakas = new char[4][3];


    // constructor - initialize
    public Board() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                pinakas[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    // Fill board with *
    public void fillBoard1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                pinakas[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    // Fill board with A
    public void fillBoard2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                pinakas[i][j] = 'A';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, i'm going insane 
(i'm Using Eclipse and coding in Java (huehue))

Comment: Please reserve the mentioning and tagging of questions with IDE (eclipse) tags to those which deal with the IDE itself. Highly unlikely is the case an IDE is the source of your *programming* problem.

Comment: what line of he code has this error?

Comment: soz for using a wrong tag, didn't know what i was facing, solution was simple and i saw my mistake, i even edited the post so it involves no reference to something not connected with this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have 2 option to initialize your array: 
1. you can put it like that in the top of the class:

```
public char pinakas[][] = new char[4][3];
```

*please note that in java, most of the programmers will put the [] after the variable and not after its name*
2. you can declare it in the top of the class and initialize in the constructor:

```
public char pinakas[][];

public Board()
{
    pinakas = new char[4][3];
    //here you can do whatever you want
}
```

Second, you have an `array` in a size of [4][3].
in the for loops you are passing from 0 to 4 (including 4) and from 0 to 3 (including 3).
actually, you have 5 possible values for the first position. and 4 for the second position.
so, what will happen is even if you do manage to solve 1 problem you will get `OutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you can't have expressions in a class body. While this would be fine:

```
public char pinakas[][] = new char[4][3];
```

What you currently have is not.

Comment: In java you can do it both way.

Comment: @afzalex Can you really? I actually didn't know that.

Edit: Yep, just tried it. afzelex is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have this piece of code just hanging there inside of your class

```
pinakas = new char[4][3];
```

It has to be inside a method or constructor.
Or you can simply initialize your variable at the same time you are defining it:

```
public char pinakas[][] = new char[4][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are separating expressions into two lines in a Java class, which is invalid. Code can be executed like that only in a method. You just need to combine the two lines into a single one:

Change:

```
public char pinakas[][]; 
pinakas = new char[4][3];
```

To:

```
public char pinakas[][] = new char[4][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your 2 lines for your pinkas array into one, like so:

```
public char pinakas[][] = new char[4][3];
```

Then, you need to fix your for loop when filling up your array so you don't get an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception:

```
public Board() {
    //You were using 5 and 4
    //When you should be using 4 and 3
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            pinakas[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...
public char a[][] = new char[2][3];

I think Eclipse is not supporting array declaration followed by initialization inside the class outside the methods.

Answer (score 0):

simply use:

```
char pinakas[][]=new char[5][4];
```

Avoid declaration and initialisation in diiferent steps or do that outside the class.

**OR use :**

```
char pinakas[][]=new char[4][3];
```

then change the limit of each iteration(decrement each of them by one).